# Bash script with sudo installs files in root's home directory, How can I fix this?

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

So, I'm working on my first bash script, it is to install my dotfiles on a new system,there's a few `git clones` and this messes up things because it install them in the root's home directory when the script is executed with `sudo`

There's basically three things that I need to do as root:

1. Install packages
2. move some of the fonts that I get with `git clone`, to `/usr/share/fonts` ( I could put them in ~/.fonts but I don't want a folder in my home directory for just one font that I use)
3. Move .vimrc file into root's home directory (I have a specific .vimrc for root)

I could do the steps above manually but the reason I'm doing a script is to avoid doing that.

How can I do this without installing or git cloning everything else in root's home directory ?

Here's the script I have so far.

PS: This is my first script, I hope it doesn't look that bad.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "$HOME/.dotfiles" ]; then
    echo "============================"
    echo "== Installing dotfiles... =="
    echo "============================"
    git clone --separate-git-dir="$HOME"/.dotfiles https://github.com/username/dotfiles.git my-dotfiles-tmp >/dev/null 2>&1;
    rsync --recursive --verbose --exclude '.git' my-dotfiles-tmp/ "$HOME"/ >/dev/null 2>&1;
    rm --recursive my-dotfiles-tmp >/dev/null 2>&1;
else
    echo "Can't make install, '$HOME/.dotfiles' folder already exist"
    exit
fi

if [ -f "$HOME/.zshrc" ]; then
    mv .zshrc .zshrc.bak
fi

# create necessary directories
mkdir -p $HOME/.config/zsh/plugins/{colored-man-pages,syntax-highlighting,zsh-autosuggestions}

# git clone necessary zsh extensions
git clone https://github.com/ael-code/zsh-colored-man-pages.git ~/.config/zsh/plugins/colored-man-pages >/dev/null 2>&1
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git ~/.config/zsh/plugins/syntax-highlighting >/dev/null 2>&1
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.git ~/.config/zsh/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions >/dev/null 2>&1

# neovim set up
sh -c 'curl -fLo "${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim' >/dev/null 2>&1

function config {
   /usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME $@
}
config config status.showUntrackedFiles no

# clear terminal
clear

echo "=========="
echo "== Done =="
echo "=========="

# reload zsh
zsh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: If running script as root then $HOME will be root's home. You have to specify which user and then use that users /home.

Comment: Try putting cd $HOME above your git statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use rsync for the commands.

```
rsync -a user@123.456.789.012:/github.com/ael-code/zsh-colored-man-pages.git ~/.config/zsh/plugins/
```

You are only doing a single file at a time it is a simple matter. If the place you store the files allows a shell access account so a .ssh/authorized_keys can be created it can be done without a password.

The command above uses the rsync program to make an archival copy of the /github.com/ael-code/zsh-colored-man-pages.git to the directory on the computer it runs on of ~/.config/zsh/plugins/. A straight copy of the file is made check-summed and guaranteed to be byte for byte copy or it fails to copy it with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Created file test.sh with just this:

```
echo $HOME

fred@z170-focal-k:~$ bash test.sh 
/home/fred
fred@z170-focal-k:~$ sudo bash test.sh
[sudo] password for fred: 
/root
```

If not clear, then it should be that is is best to always give full paths and not use system variables which may be interpreted differently  depending on multiple conditions.